# Is adding and removing event listeners anti-pattern in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Consider this snippet,

```
useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('mousedown', checkAndCloseMenu);
        return () => document.removeEventListener('mousedown', checkAndCloseMenu);
 }, []);
```

I am using this useEffect in an Higher Order Dropdown Component, I've seen very few professionals using these kinds of adding and remove Event Listeners. Is using these eventListeners anti-pattern ? If yes, what would be the correct approach.

Comment: If you want to listen on the document then this looks correct, except that `checkAndCloseMenu` should probably be inside the useEffect.

Comment: Hi, maybe can you post it as an answer ? so that I could mark it as answer, it might be helpful to other coders too ?

Comment: The anti-pattern here most likely would be not to have `checkAndCloseMenu` in effect dependencies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding and removing event listeners is not considered an anti-pattern.

```
useEffect(() => {
  document.addEventListener('mousedown', checkAndCloseMenu);
  return () => document.removeEventListener('mousedown', checkAndCloseMenu);
 }, []);
```

Whenever/wherever possible it is preferred to use a React ref to access underlying DOMNodes:

```
const ref = React.useRef();

useEffect(() => {
  const node = ref.current;

  node.addEventListener('mousedown', checkAndCloseMenu);
  return () => node.removeEventListener('mousedown', checkAndCloseMenu);
 }, []);

 ...

 <div ref={ref}> ..... </div>
```

or to attach the listeners directly

```
<div onMouseDown={checkAndCloseMenu}> ..... </div>
```

but sometimes this is unavoidable when you need to listen to event from the `window` and `document` objects/nodes.

What ***is*** considered anti-pattern is directly mutating a global event listener.

```
document.onmousedown = checkAndCloseMenu;
```

Not only does doing so mutate a global object it will replace any existing values there. Don't do event handling like this.